# Laravel after save model need to refresh it to use the relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm struggling with weird problem, don't know if it should considered as a bug.

I have this code on update process:

```
    // initial $invoice->user_updated_id = 1

    $invoice = $this->find($id); // Invoice::findOrFail($id)
    $userId = Auth::user()->id; // $userId = 2
    $request = array_merge($request, ['user_updated_id' => $userId]);
    $invoice->fill($request);
    $invoice->save();

    Log::info('Attribute: ' . $invoice->user_updated_id);
    Log::info('Relation: ' . $invoice->userUpdated->id); // Basic relationship to User model.
```

The output is:

```
local.INFO: Attribute: 2
local.INFO: Relation: 1
```

Why after saving the model the relationship is still getting the old model?

If I rewrite the code with:

```
    // initial $invoice->user_updated_id = 1

    $invoice = $this->find($id);
    $userId = Auth::user()->id; // $userId = 2
    $request = array_merge($request, ['user_updated_id' => $userId]);
    $invoice->fill($request);
    $invoice->save();
    $invoice->refresh();

    Log::info('Attribute: ' . $invoice->user_updated_id);
    Log::info('Relation: ' . $invoice->userUpdated->id); // Basic relationship to User model.
```

The output is:

```
local.INFO: Attribute: 2
local.INFO: Relation: 2
```

Comment: This is a normal behavior. Not sure what `$this->find($id)` does, but most likely the relation is already loaded with the old id and after you save the new attributes the relation does not automatically load with the new id.

Comment: `$this->find($id)` only retrieves the model object. But there is a way to manage reloading relationships after save? Or I just need do the refresh() method always I want the reloaded relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `refresh` call works but it's also redundant because it refreshes the main model you've just saved before, and you probably don't want to do this because its data are good. To refresh only relationships, you can use `load('userUpdated')` or `loadMissing('userUpdated')` methods. `load` loads some relationships even if they are already loaded whereas `loadMissing` does it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Just state the relationship you want to retrive as parameter on the load method,

```
 $invoice = $this->find($id);
 $userId = Auth::user()->id; // $userId = 2
 $request = array_merge($request, ['user_updated_id' => $userId]);
 $invoice->fill($request);
 $invoice->save();
 $invoice->load('userUpdated');//this relation ship
```

you can even call nested relationships, for example if you want a user and his contacts, provided inside user model you stated the relationship with contacts
you can do as below

```
$invoice->load('user.contact'); //and this was just an example
```